# How to fine tune Tesseract 4.1.1?

Tags: lstm, tesseract, training-data

I am trying to fine tune Tesseract, but I am not successful. I already have a .treineddata file provided with LSTM training. I already have .png and .box too ... How do I fine tune? I need to increase the accuracy of OCR for my documents...
(I already searched the documentation and other forums, but nothing solved my problem).

Comment: You can do some preprocessing before the input image is going to the ocr

Comment: I already made that....